# Python find next file by natural sort

Tags: python, path

I'm trying to find the next file by natural sorting with a depth variable but am facing some problems.

the folder structure is following:

```
tests/
------test1/
-----------test2/
----------------...
----------------30.jpg
----------------31.jpg
-----------test3/
----------------...
----------------30.jpg
----------------31.jpg
-----------1.jpg
------1.jpg
```

I want to reach the next or the item before my current item, iterating over them with the forward and backward function.
Getting items on the same level is working currently, also to get one on the max depth level.

For example I want to get with the backwards function on

```
path=tests/test1/test2/1.jpg
```

the result

```
tests/test1/1.jpg
```

but with

```
path=tests/test1/test3/1.jpg
```

the result

```
tests/test1/test2/31.jpg
```

obviously reversed results same with the forward functions.
My current problem is finding the next file on the next level without repeating myself and building a loop, iterating through the folders worked completely fine so far, but I'm currently completely stuck on this one.

My current code so far:

```
import os
import re

import wx


class PathSelect(wx.App):
    """
    path select application
    """

    def __init__(self):
        """
        initializing function

        :return:
        """
        super(PathSelect, self).__init__()

    @staticmethod
    def ask_path():
        """
        ask for our starting path

        :return:
        """
        wildcard = ("Image Files (*.*)|*.jpeg;*.jpg;*.png;*.bmp|"
                    "Joint Photographic Experts Group (*.jpeg;*.jpg)|*.jpeg;*.jpg|"
                    "Portable Network Graphics (*.png)|*.png|"
                    "Bitmap (*.bmp)|*.bmp|"
                    "All files (*.*)|*.*")
        dialog = wx.FileDialog(None, "Choose a file", os.getcwd(), "", wildcard, wx.FD_OPEN | wx.FD_FILE_MUST_EXIST)
        if dialog.ShowModal() == wx.ID_OK:
            return dialog.GetPath()
        dialog.Destroy()


class PathingAlgorithm(object):
    """
    our pathing algorithm
    """

    def __init__(self, depth=1):
        """
        initializing function

        :return:
        """
        self.depth = depth
        self.image_path = ""

    @staticmethod
    def natural_sort(current_list):
        convert = lambda text: int(text) if text.isdigit() else text.lower()
        alphanum_key = lambda key: [convert(c) for c in re.split('([0-9]+)', key)]
        return sorted(current_list, key=alphanum_key)

    def current(self):
        """
        return the current path or ask for the path

        :return:
        """
        if not self.image_path:
            self.image_path = PathSelect.ask_path()
        if self.image_path:
            return self.image_path

    def backward(self, path="", depth=0, ghost=False):
        """
        return path for the previous picture

        :param path:
        :param depth:
        :param ghost:
        :return:
        """
        # max recursion case, break our function here
        if self.depth < depth:
            return None

        depth += 1
        if path == "":
            path = self.image_path
        folder = os.path.dirname(path)
        file_name = os.path.basename(path)
        folder_content = self.natural_sort(os.listdir(folder))
        file_index = folder_content.index(file_name)
        if file_index == 0:
            path = self.backward(folder, depth, ghost)
            # handle max depth case
            if path is None:
                return None
            # get in the same level of the foldertree again if possible
            for x in xrange(depth):
                path_list = os.listdir(path)
                if path_list:
                    path = os.path.join(path, self.natural_sort(path_list)[len(path_list) - 1])
        else:
            path = os.path.join(folder, folder_content[folder_content.index(file_name) - 1])
        if not ghost:
            self.image_path = path
        return path

    def forward(self, path="", depth=0, ghost=False):
        """
        return path for the next picture

        :param path:
        :param depth:
        :return:
        """
        depth += 1
        # max recursion case, break our function here
        if self.depth < depth:
            return None

        # on start use current path, on recursion skip this
        if path == "":
            path = self.image_path

        folder = os.path.dirname(path)
        file_name = os.path.basename(path)
        if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(folder, file_name)):
            folders = os.listdir(folder)
        else:
            folders = [name for name in os.listdir(folder) if os.path.isdir(os.path.join(folder, name))]
        folder_content = self.natural_sort(folders)
        file_index = folder_content.index(file_name)
        if file_index == len(folder_content) - 1:
            if self.depth - 1 < depth:
                files = [name for name in os.listdir(folder) if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(folder, name))]
                if files:
                    return os.path.join(folder, files[0])
            path = self.forward(folder, depth, ghost)
            # handle max depth case
            if path is None:
                return None
            # get in the same level of the foldertree again if possible
            for x in xrange(depth):
                if not os.path.isfile(path):
                    file_list = os.listdir(path)
                    if file_list:
                        path = os.path.join(path, self.natural_sort(file_list)[0])
        else:
            path = os.path.join(folder, folder_content[folder_content.index(file_name) + 1])
        if not ghost:
            self.image_path = path
        return path


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App()
    app.MainLoop()
    ps = PathingAlgorithm(depth=3)
    # print ps.current()
    # print ps.backward(ghost=True)
    # print ps.forward(ghost=True)
    print ps.forward(
        path='../tests/test1/test2/31.jpg',
        ghost=True,
    )
```

thanks for any help in advance

Comment: Do you know of the [`glob` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/glob.html#module-glob)? It can return a full list across different levels of directories for files that match a simple regex. It might do what you need, or at least help.

Comment: thanks it helped me, the glob module isn't returning all files from the sub directory, but fnmatch could combined for os.walk. Somehow I was way too cramped to do it with a recursive function instead of just sorting the created file tree.

Comment: If you've got it working that's great! Glad to help a tiny bit. Feel free to post an answer showing how you did it for anyone else with this problem that comes across your question.

Comment: Ah sorry, I think you misunderstood me. You can post your solution as an answer. On SO it's encouraged to [post an actual answer on your own question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) if you've worked out a solution.

Comment: thanks a lot, didn't see it, again thanks for the help^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was too focused on the recursive function, solving it over a sorted file tree was the solution, currently not the best performance is the depth is too big and it wants to get all files, but good enough for my case

```
def get_file_tree(self, path):
    """
    return a natural sorted file tree and the index of your original file

    :param path:
    :return:
    """
    if not os.path.exists(path):
        return None
    filename = os.path.basename(path)
    basepath = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(path))
    for _ in xrange(self.depth):
        path = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(basepath, os.pardir))

    # list all files
    configfiles = [os.path.join(dirpath, f)
                   for dirpath, dirnames, files in os.walk(path)
                   for f in fnmatch.filter(files, '*')]
    # use natural sort for the tree
    configfiles = self.natural_sort(configfiles)
    original_path = os.path.join(basepath, filename)
    original_index = configfiles.index(original_path)
    return configfiles, original_index

def backward(self, path="", ghost=False):
    """
    get the next file of our current or defined path

    :param path:
    :param ghost:
    :return:
    """
    if path == "":
        path = self.image_path
    path = os.path.abspath(path)

    configfiles, original_index = self.get_file_tree(path)
    # if file was non existant or the index was 0 return None
    if original_index is None or original_index == 0:
        return None
    new_path = configfiles[original_index - 1]
    if new_path.count("\\") > path.count("\\"):
        return None
    if not ghost:
        self.image_path = new_path
    return new_path

def forward(self, path="", ghost=False):
    """
    get the next file of our current or defined path

    :param path:
    :param ghost:
    :return:
    """
    if path == "":
        path = self.image_path
    path = os.path.abspath(path)

    configfiles, original_index = self.get_file_tree(path)
    # if file was non existant or was the last file, return None
    if original_index is None or len(configfiles) <= original_index + 1:
        return None
    new_path = configfiles[original_index + 1]
    if not ghost:
        self.image_path = new_path
    return new_path
```